# SpringBatch @Async method not working in persistent layer (JPAItemWriter)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch

SpringBoot Application with SpringBatch and JPA, without @Async all working fine but with @Async added in the REST API the job is completed but JPAItemWriter is not persisting the objects in the DB. looks like Transactional problem as am getting this exception.

Transaction Manager [org.sringframework.batch.support.transaction.**ResourcelessTransactionManager] does not support transaction suspension**.

I tried with different approaches like changing Propagation.Requires_New (Required, Supports) but nothing works, tried searching all the forums but no luck.

```
@Service 
public class SampleWriter extends JpaItemWriter<TestEntity> {
       @Autowired
       EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    @Override
    public void write(List<TestEntity> entities) {
          this.doWrite(entityManager, entities);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are configuring and using Spring Batch in a wrong way.

Firstly, it is using the default `BatchConfigurer` which the `TransactionManager` is `ResourcelessTransactionManager` that is mainly use for testing or acts as a "no-op" `TransactionManager` for the batch job that does not require any transaction which is definitely not your case now.

Secondly, Spring Batch will internally take care of managing the transaction boundary for processing each chunk , you do not need to extend `JpaItemWriter` and control the transaction behaviour using  `@Transactional` by yourself.

So , read this [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) for how to configure Spring Batch , especially the part related to `BatchConfigurer`

On the other hand if you are using Spring-boot , it should already configure a  [`JpaBatchConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/JpaBatchConfigurer.java) for you.

Comment: No, you are wrong, PlatformTransactionManager and DataSource are injected in the stepbuilderfactory, we use JpaItemWriter in order to persist the entity pojos as it has an doWrite API. no problem in using JPAItemWriter just that in async mode transaction is not in the current context thats why we get that exception, since it works fine without any issue in Normal mode.

Comment: OK. just one simple question to ask and think it by yourself , why you inject `ResourcelessTransactionManager` but not `JpaTransactionManager` ? If you configure spring-batch properly and do not misuse it , you should inject `JpaTransactionManager`. Show me more codes or put a minimal and reproducible  sample project into some Github , I am happy to look into it if I think you are humble and polite enough to listen and think about about other people 's opinion that is against your thought before saying it is wrong. Otherwise , good luck to you

Comment: you may be correct, i really don't understand how Async method works internally, let me create a sample project of this use-case...still wonder how does it work fine without Async method. Thanks a lot for you time and help - really appreciate it.

Comment: you know what, your hint actually worked...i just removed the PlatformTransactionManager and used JpaTransactionManager and everything worked. Thanks a lot again...keep it up..